# Completely remove npm link

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-link

On my Mac, I accidentally use `npm link` in a project root directly. Now every time I install packages it's getting from our proxy service. I want to remove that link. How can I do that? I removed node, npm, and nvm also. Thank you.